# Find the set of points that lies inside an open $2D$ Cone or find a point lies inside an open $2D$ Cone (which ever is easier)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

So the question goes like this, I have an open $2D$ Cone, which is defined by its cone axis and a symmetric angle, the equation of the axis cone is $x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta=r$ and the symmetric angle about axis cone is $\omega$ (i.e. half cone angle is $\frac{\omega}{2}$).

The figure bellow gives an apt description of situation.

[image: Fig1]

We see that origin of cone is at a distance of $d$ from the normal. Now the question is to find the set of points $\{x,y\}$ that lie inside this cone.

**Approach till now**

If the cone is present at the origin as shown in figure below, then the set of points that lie inside the cone is given as

$$R = \left\{(x,y)\; \big|\; \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\omega}{2} \leq \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \leq \frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\omega}{2}\right\}$$

[image: Fig2]

So how can I extend it to my case. I have found answers given by people for similar questions, i.e., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3770279/calculating-intersections-of-a-2d-cone-and-segments) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167022/2d-geometry-how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-an-angle), and I think they can be helpful.

In the first of the two posts, if we know the end points of cone(i.e. not an open cone), we can determine whether a point is lying inside or outside the cone.

In the second post, they use vector algebra to find whether a point lies inside a 2D open cone.

Any hints and directions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the points $(x,y)$ of the **basic circular sector**:

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

must satisfy the inequalities:

$$
|y|\cos\frac{\omega}{2} \le x\sin\frac{\omega}{2}
\quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad
x^2 + y^2 \le R^2
$$

recalling the relations of a *plane rototranslation*:

$$
\begin{cases}
x' = x_C + x\cos\phi - y\sin\phi \\
y' = y_C + y\cos\phi + x\sin\phi \\
\end{cases}
\quad \Rightarrow \quad
\begin{cases}
x = (x'-x_C)\cos\phi + (y'-y_C)\sin\phi \\
y = (y'-y_C)\cos\phi - (x'-x_C)\sin\phi \\
\end{cases}
$$

it follows that the points $(x,y)$ of the **rototranslated circular sector**:

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

must satisfy the inequalities:

$$
\left|(y-y_C)\cos\phi-(x-x_C)\sin\phi\right|\cos\frac{\omega}{2} \le \left((x-x_C)\cos\phi+(y-y_C)\sin\phi\right)\sin\frac{\omega}{2}
$$

$$
\text{and}
$$

$$
(x-x_C)^2 + (y-y_C)^2 \le R^2
$$

with $R \ge 0$, $0 \le \phi \le 2\pi$, $0 \le \omega \le 2\pi$.

In your specific case:

- $R \to \infty$, so the second inequality is true for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$;
- $(x_C,\,y_C) = \left(r\cos\theta+d\sin\theta,\,r\sin\theta-d\cos\theta\right)$;
- $\phi = \theta + \frac{\pi}{2}$;

so the desired inequality is:

$$
\boxed{\left|r-x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta\right|\cos\frac{\omega}{2} \le \left(d-x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta\right)\sin\frac{\omega}{2}}
$$

with $d \ge 0$, $r \ge 0$, $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$, $0 \le \omega \le 2\pi$.

Comment: How have you derived the first inequality?, any hints are appreciated

Comment: Are you sure about the coordinates of origin of circular sector i.e. $(x_C,\,y_C) = \left(r\cos\theta+d\sin\theta,\,r\sin\theta-d\cos\theta\right)$? What I derived is $(x_C,\,y_C) = \left((r-d)\cos\theta,\,(r-d)\sin\theta\right)$. I found them by solving distance formula of a point on a line and point slope form simultaneously. Thanks

Comment: Found my mistake, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The direction of the axis of this $2D$ cone is given by the unit vector

$a = (- \sin \theta, \cos \theta ) $

And the vertex of the cone is the point $V = (x_0, y_0) $

Given a point $P = (x , y)$ , compute the displacement vector from the vertex to the point,

$ u = P - V $

Then the angle that $u$ makes with the axis satisfies

$ \cos \phi = \dfrac{ u \cdot a }{ \| u \|}  = \dfrac{ u^T a }{\sqrt{ u^T u} }$

Since we want to be inside the cone then we require

$ \cos \phi \gt \cos \left(\dfrac{\omega}{2} \right) $

Squaring, and re-arranging, the condition becomes

$ u^T \left( {a a}^T - \cos^2 \left(\dfrac{\omega}{2}\right) I_2 \right) u \gt 0 $

And, in addition, we must have

$ u^T a \gt 0 $

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time, I understood your answer well.